# cannot add in vba the same name but different in age

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If cmdAdd.Caption = "ADD" Then
txtName.Enabled = True: cboAge.Enabled = True:
cmdAdd.Caption = "SAVE": cmdClose.Caption = "CANCEL"
txtName.SetFocus
Else
If txtName.Text = "" Or cboAge.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Required field(s) missing!", vbCritical, "Message"
Else
For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If (txtName.Text) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
MsgBox "Record already exist!", vbExclamation, "Message"
Call UserForm_Activate
Exit Sub
End If
Next i
r = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value = (txtName.Text)
Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value = cboAge.Text
r = 0
MsgBox "One record saved!", vbInformation, "Message"
Call UserForm_Activate
End If
End If
End Sub*
```

this code is for adding a name and age to the sheet,my problem is that there is already the 
name and age in sheet but then if im going to add with the same name but not the same age it cannot able to add, even the information is not the same.
hope you will help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only testing if the name is the same and exiting if it is. To test if both name and age are the same, change this:

```
If (txtName.Text) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
MsgBox "Record already exist!", vbExclamation, "Message"
```

to this:

```
If txtName.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value And _ 
    cboAge.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
MsgBox "Record already exist!", vbExclamation, "Message"
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to click the checkmark next to my answer.